# ¿Cómo inyectar correctamente una clase en otra clase con @Autowired en Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Tengo una claseA que implementa una interfaceA, con un methodA, luego tengo una claseB en la que llamo claseA con un @Autowired para poder usar methodA, pero me da una advertencia de que debo crear un método para claseA.  ¿Por qué está pasando esto?  ¿No funciona @Autowired así en este caso?  ¿Debería crear una instancia de claseA?  Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

ClaseA

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class RepositoryImpl implements IRepository {

    @Autowired
    private final TransactionDataMapper transactionDataMapper;

     @Autowired
     private SpringDataColminvoice 
     springDataColminvoice;//segunda

    @Override
    public <S extends TransactionDto> S save(S s) {
    

    Colm colm = transactionDataMapper.toEntity(s);
    **methodA**
    springDataColminvoice.save(colm);
    return null;
}
```

InterfazA

```
        public interface IRepository extends 
        IRepository<TransactionDto, Integer>{
        }
```

ClaseB

```
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   @Service
   public class ServiceImpl implements IInvoiceService {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryImpl repositoryImpl;
    

   @Override
   public void save(CMessage cMessage) 
   throws HandlerException {
    try {

     TransactionDto transactionDto = cMessage.getTransaction();
     
     
    **methodA**
    repositoryImpl.save(transactionDto);


     } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HandlerException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Action:

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field RepositoryImpl in com.st.ms.yyu.d.binvoce.infraestructure.rest.spring.services.impl.InvoiceServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.st.ms.yyu.d.binvoce.infraestructure.db.springdata.repository.impl.ServiceImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

          Consider defining a bean of type 'com.st.ms.yyu.d.binvoce.infraestructure.db.springdata.repository.impl.RepositoryImpl' in your configuration.
```

Comment: El autowiring solo funciona en clases que están marcadas como componentes de spring... sea `@Component`, `@Service` o `@Bean`. Te recomiendo marcar la clase `RepositoryImpl` como un `@Service` o `@Component` si vas a intentar inyectarlo. En realidad cual de las 3 anotaciones uses da un poco igual, puesto que la diferencia es mayormente léxica para identificar las clases mientras programamos. La excepción sería `@Bean`, el cual tiene un uso particular a la hora de *encapsular* objetos en su propio bean, muy útil a la hora de trabajar con librerías externas por ejemplo :)

Comment: Por cierto, también existe la opción de usar la anotación `@Repository`, la cual también es usada para activar el escaneo de clases y la inyección de las mismas.

Comment: Gracias, le coloqué @Service pero sigue dándome la misma excepción.

Comment: @Jhon a qué clase le colocaste @Service?

Comment: @AndresGardiol a RepositoryImpl

Answer (score 0):

Deberías quitar en la classe `RepositoryImpl` el `@RequiredArgsConstructor` ya que todos los atributos son autowired por lo que no será necesario inicializarlos en un constructor.

También tienes que añadir la anotación `@Component` o `@Repository` o `@Service` a la clase `RepositoryImpl`.

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow! Te recomiendo que leas [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta aún más. Agrega el código con la solución que propones, así es más fácil entender cómo arreglar el problema

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).